# How to share https connections on port 443 with two different servers

Tags: apache, tomcat, virtualhost

I have a site with two servers, apache2 and Tomcat7. 
Apache2 listens to 80, while tomcat7 to 443. 
Apache2 is needed to present a Wordpress blog, while Tomcat7 to serve a JSP site.
My virtualhosts scheme in Apache is like this:

> http://blog.example.com ---> DefaultRoot for the blog
>   http://example.com      ---> Redirect to https://example.com  (where Tomcat listens)
>   Everything works fine. My original site in JSP always responds in https secure mode, while I have a working Wordpress in my "blog." subdomain.
>   The problem comes now that I want that blog interact with https (without any ugly 3rd port in the url if possible)

Making Apache2 to listen at 443 will obviously come to a conflict about 'port in use'.
Disabling it in Tomcat7 has no sense as somewhere it has to listen for ssl.

The question for you is: How would you face it?

Comment: You cannot use the same port (e.g 443) for different services. What you can do is to configure the Apache to listen on port 443 and to redirect 'example.com' requests to the Tomcat (e.g using AJP protocol), whereas 'blog.example.com' requests are still served by the Apache.

Comment: In that case, where should be listening Tomcat?

Comment: The Tomcat AJP connector (e.g port 8009) should be enough. If you still need to directly access Tomcat you can maintain the HTTP connectors; for example on port 8080.

Comment: Then, do I have to understand that an https connection would be handled by Apache? I am going to check

Comment: Yes, you can configure the https connection in Apache. Usually in this types of configurations the Tomcat service is not exposed to the outside.

Comment: The thing now is, in my very particular case, having a proxy will be a problem for the app as my users will use microprocessors with very limited software that won't handle redirects... Could I do the same in the opposite direction? it is redirecting from tomcat:443 to apache